# HashMap: One Key, multiple Values

Tags: java

How I can get the third value for the first key in this map? Is this possible?

Comment: I can get the first value for a key by using the member function of HashMap::get though the third one? I cannot find any code unfortunately.

Comment: You cannot find your own code? That's what he is talking about.

Comment: Sounds like you might be a little confused about the difference between keys and hashed keys. Hopefully this will set you straight: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap

Comment: A Map can't have multiple values for one key, but you can have a Collection as value instead

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Libraries exist to do this, but the simplest plain Java way is to create a `Map` of `List` like this:

```
Map<Object,ArrayList<Object>> multiMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: However, it may well be simpler to use a library than to roll your own, test it etc...

Comment: this solution would only work if the objects in the ArrayList are from the same type. S, f.e. it's not possible to have a key with a int and a double value..

Comment: @JonSkeet which is the recommended library for this use case?

Comment: @gaurav: It's been so long since I've been in the Java world that I wouldn't like to say. I'd look at Guava though.

Answer (score 35):

It sounds like you're looking for a [*multimap*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has various [`Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.java) implementations, usually created via the [`Multimaps`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.java) class.

I would suggest that using that implementation is likely to be simpler than rolling your own, working out what the API should look like, carefully checking for an existing list when adding a value etc. If your situation has a particular aversion to third party libraries it may be worth doing that, but otherwise Guava is a fabulous library which will probably help you with other code too :)

Comment: Apache Commons Collections has also a [Multimap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) implementation.

Answer (score 26):

For example:

```
Map<Object,Pair<Integer,String>> multiMap = new HashMap<Object,Pair<Integer,String>>();
```

where the `Pair` is a parametric class

```
public class Pair<A, B> {
    A first = null;
    B second = null;

    Pair(A first, B second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public A getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(A first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public B getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(B second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is what i found in a similar question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536803/1174987)

```
Map<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("Value 1");
values.add("Value 2");
hm.put("Key1", values);

// to get the arraylist
System.out.println(hm.get("Key1"));
```

RESULT: [Value 1, Value 2]

Answer (score 12):

A standard Java HashMap cannot store multiple values per key, any new entry you add will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 10):

Have you got something like this?

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

If so, you can iterate through your ArrayList and get the item you like with arrayList.get(i).

Comment: how to add elements to arraylist and iterate

Answer (score 7):

I found the blog on random search, i think this will help for doing this: http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com.tr/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html

```
public class MutliMapTest {
public static void main(String... args) {
   Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   // Adding some key/value
   myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
   myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
   myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
   myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

   // Getting the size
   int size = myMultimap.size();
   System.out.println(size);  // 4

   // Getting values
   Collection<String> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
   System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]

   Collection<string> vegetables = myMultimap.get("Vegetables");
   System.out.println(vegetables); // [Carrot]

   // Iterating over entire Mutlimap
   for(String value : myMultimap.values()) {
      System.out.println(value);
   }

   // Removing a single value
   myMultimap.remove("Fruits","Pear");
   System.out.println(myMultimap.get("Fruits")); // [Bannana, Pear]

   // Remove all values for a key
   myMultimap.removeAll("Fruits");
   System.out.println(myMultimap.get("Fruits")); // [] (Empty Collection!)
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using collections to store the values of a key:

```
Map<Key, Collection<Value>>
```

you have to maintain the value list yourself

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons collection classes is the solution.

```
    MultiMap multiMapDemo = new MultiValueMap();

    multiMapDemo .put("fruit", "Mango");
    multiMapDemo .put("fruit", "Orange");
    multiMapDemo.put("fruit", "Blueberry");

    System.out.println(multiMap.get("fruit"));
   // Mango Orange Blueberry
```

Maven Dependency

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -- 
     >
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
         <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the answers here, I have a solution that I used and found it most useful if you **know the length of multiple values to be added to your key.**

In my case, it was 2, so I opted for this over a `List<string>.`

```
HashMap<String, String[]> multimap= new HashMap<>();
multimap.put("my_key", new String[]{"my_value1", "my_value2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about a Map with 2 keys immediately compelled me to use a user-defined key, and that would probably be a Class. Following is the key Class:

```
public class MapKey {
    private Object key1;
    private Object key2;

    public Object getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public void setKey1(Object key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }

    public Object getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    public void setKey2(Object key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
}


// Create first map entry with key <A,B>.
        MapKey mapKey1 = new MapKey();
        mapKey1.setKey1("A");
        mapKey1.setKey2("B");
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap – Single Key and Multiple Values Using List

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  // create list one and store values

    List<String> One = new ArrayList<String>();
    One.add("Apple");
    One.add("Aeroplane");

    // create list two and store values
    List<String> Two = new ArrayList<String>();
    Two.add("Bat");
    Two.add("Banana");

    // put values into map
    map.put("A", One);
    map.put("B", Two);
    map.put("C", Three);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (add access modifiers as required):

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> complexMap=new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
```

You can insert data like this:

```
    Map<String,String> componentMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    componentMap.put("foo","bar");
    componentMap.put("secondFoo","secondBar");
    complexMap.put("superFoo",componentMap);
```

The Generated Data Structure would be:

```
{superFoo={secondFoo=secondBar, foo=bar}}
```

**This way each value for the key should have a unique identifier**. Also gives O(1) for fetches,if keys are known.

Answer (score 0):

Write a new class that holds all the values that you need and use the new class's object as the value in your HashMap

```
HashMap<String, MyObject>

class MyObject {
public String value1;
public int value2;
public List<String> value3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code how to get extract the hashmap into arrays, hashmap that contains arraylist

```
Map<String, List<String>> country_hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

//Creating two lists and inserting some data in it
List<String> list_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list_1.add("16873538.webp");
list_1.add("16873539.webp");

List<String> list_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list_2.add("16873540.webp");
list_2.add("16873541.webp");

//Inserting both the lists and key to the Map 
country_hashmap.put("Malaysia", list_1);
country_hashmap.put("Japanese", list_2);

for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> hashmap_data : country_hashmap.entrySet()){
      String key = hashmap_data.getKey(); // contains the keys
      List<String> val = hashmap_data.getValue(); // contains arraylists
      // print all the key and values in the hashmap
      System.out.println(key + ": " +val);
      
      // using interator to get the specific values arraylists
      Iterator<String> itr = val.iterator();
      int i = 0;
      String[] data = new String[val.size()];
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            String array = itr.next();
            data[i] = array;
            System.out.println(data[i]); // GET THE VALUE
            i++;
        }
  }
```