# Multiple values for a key in HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it possible to keep multiple values corresponding to a key in a HashMap? If yes, how?

Comment: for example, by storing container type, such as `List`, as value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashMap: One Key, multiple Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229473/hashmap-one-key-multiple-values)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is called chaining. You will want to avoid chaining as much as possible, especially if the size of the chain starts increasing. Longer chain size will counter the whole purpose of using a hash structure because the goal is to come as close to O(1) as possible.

```
Map<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("Value 1");
values.add("Value 2");
hm.put("Key1", values);
```

Comment: how can i get the values of "List" for key "Key1"

Answer (score 9):

You could give a shot at [Guava library](http://github.com/google/guava/) (former Google collections). It has implementations of Multimaps which can store multiple values for a single key.

For example [ListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap) implementations allow duplicate key/value pairs which are kept in insertion order.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> numberClasses = ArrayListMultimap.create();
numberClasses.put("odd", 1);
numberClasses.put("odd", 3);
numberClasses.put("odd", 5);

numberClasses.put("even", 2);
numberClasses.put("even", 4);
numberClasses.put("even", 6);

assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1,3,5), numberClasses.get("odd"));
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(2,4,6), numberClasses.get("even"));
```

Another cool example would be [SetMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap), which is very similar to ListMultimap except that values for a key are kept in a set. (From user perspective, I don't know how exactly it is implemented.)

```
SetMultimap<String, Integer> setMultimap= HashMultimap.create();
setMultimap.put("key1", 1);
setMultimap.put("key1", 1);
setMultimap.put("key1", 1);
setMultimap.put("key1", 2);

setMultimap.put("key2", 1);
setMultimap.put("key2", 3);

assertEquals(ImmutableSet.of(1,2), setMultimap.get("key1"));
assertEquals(ImmutableSet.of(1,3), setMultimap.get("key2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: or any other container, better suited for your task. For example, `Set`. Or just plain old array.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, no.

But!  You can have as your value, some kind of `Collection` and use that to store as many values as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if the value type being stored in your `Map` is an array or List:

`Map<String, List<String>> myMap`

or

`Map<String, String[]> myMap`

But it's generally bad practice to build up generic data structures inside generic data structures.

Why not write a domain-specific class that wraps the `HashMap`, and makes it easier for you to check for existence of a value, number of items per key, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Without using any other Libary
Create a map with Key as String and value as HashSet value will be not repeated string.

````
multivaleMap.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new HashSet<String>()).add("value1");
multivaleMap.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new HashSet<String>()).add("value2");

System.out.println(multivaleMap);``` will print {key=[value2, value1]}
````