# Converting List of List and String to Map with Java Stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, multimap

I have a class like this:

```
public class A {
    private List<String> stringList;
    private String someString;
}
```

I have a list of these objects like so:

```
List<A> list = //some method to generate list
```

I want to conver this to a `Map<String, String>` where each string in the `stringList` maps to the same `someString` value (like a multimap). How can I do this using java 8 stream?

I could convert this to a flat map like so:

```
list.stream.flatMap(....
```

But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Map<String, String> r = list.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.stringList.stream()
        .map(k -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(k, a.someString)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Comment: this is what i'm looking for but I get an error for `Map.Entry::getKey` saying "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: @sake1029 perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229473/hashmap-one-key-multiple-values) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536683/multiple-values-for-a-key-in-hashmap-in-java).  Basically, you'll be creating a hashmap to your list, you should avoid doing so if your list is large.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Orange", "Grape");
Map<String, String> myMap = fruits.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, String::toString));
myMap.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("key : " + k + " value : " + v));
```