# Store10 values for the same key inside Java String Collections(map,hash.etc)

Tags: java, string, collections, dictionary, hashtable

I am trying to find a way to insert all the info pertaining to the student or the faculty into some sort of String Collections(JAVA). example, maps , hashtables arraylists etc My main has the below methods which cover all name ,city..... getters setters and Tostring() a.  I read multiple [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229473/hashmap-one-key-multiple-values)  relevant to my question,but non suffices my needs.

```
public void studentStuff(){

        student.nameAge();
        student.addressparamaters();
        System.out.println(student.toSTring());

    }

public void facultyStuff(){

        faculty.nameAge();
        faculty.addressparamaters();
        System.out.println(faculty.toSTring());
```

Running my Main I get prompted for input in the following order;

```
Please Enter First Name
Mike
Please Enter Last Name
Fontain
Please Enter Age
22
Please Enter The House Number :
15
Please Enter The StreetName :
Mackay Place
Please Enter The City Name :
Long Island
Please Enter The House Zip Code:
null
Please a valid ZIP code format
11209
```

Out Put

```
 First Name: Mike
 Last Name :   Fontain
 Age :   22.0
 HOUSE NUMBER: 15
 Street Name :   Mackay
 City :   Place
 State:   Long
 Zip:   11209
```

Comment: FYI, I am not sure if the technology even exist to achieve my requirements . please advise either way. Doesn't hurt to ask:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the inherent concept of a `Class` accomplishes this for you, as long as you decide on a `key` member of the class.

```
class Student extends Person
{
    private int student_id; //if unique, good candidate for a key
    ....
    private int age,weight...;
}
```

And you can store a collection of students (or students and faculty if they extend a base class) in any sort of data structure, such as `ArrayList` etc.

```
List<Person> mylist = new ArrayList<Person>();
mylist.add(new Student(1234));
```

You can add methods to `Student`, such as overriding `toString()` to print out any important information.

If you wanted an `O(1)` access time to fetch a student based on their key, you could implement something like

```
Map<Integer,Person> mymap = new HashMap<Integer,Person>();
mymap.put(student1.getStudentID(),student1);
```

Comment: The structure of my code utilized Inheritance and Composition  clas Person{} >> class  student extends person{} etc. How is this going to work. Am I only storing the Student_ID inside my map OR Hashtable. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Right , I do have an Interface toString(){} that is implemented by all sub-classes. I am probably misunderstanding collections... i WAS THINKING THAT EVERYTHING(all values) actually get stored inside the Arraylist or any other sort of Collections ....

Comment: @user3267108 every class extends Object, so you can always override the toString() method to make it print whatever you want.

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" I owe u

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Student {
   Map<String> params = new HashMap<>()
   public Student setParameter(String paramName, String paramValue) {
      params.add(paramName, paramValue);
      return this;
   }

   public getParam(String paramName) {
      String value = param.get(paramName);
      if(value == null) value == "undef";
      return value;
   }
}
```

Do you mean something like that? You can store any parameter and retieve it knowing it's name.

Comment: That can be very useful.I Will def make that come into play somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of classes: Faculty and Student. But you want to add them to the same collection. So either both must implement same interface or extend same class. If you have common functionalities between the two classes go for extending a base class, else stick with implementing an interface.

The identification number for a person will be unique. So use a Map with key as the identification number and value as the interface or base class common for student and faculty. To learn basics about Maps refer http://preciselyconcise.com/java/collections/h_map.php . This link also gives you an idea of which map you will need to use in which situation.