# Java multiple values to one key in map

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I want to create map, where many values will be assign to one key.

Let say, that i have many toys in my database.

When i do select from database i have something like this:

name  | age to play

```
car   |  4-6
doll  |  2-4
bike  |  4-6
lego  |  6-8
plain |  6-8
```

I want to make loop in java and group everything in map, where key will be "age to play".

In my mind it will look like this:

```
2-4 -> {doll}
4-6 -> (car, bike)
6-8 -> {lego, plain}
```

I would like to make hashmap:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();

for(Toys toy : toys){

map.add(toy.age, toy.name);

}
```

But it's wrong. How i can do it ?

Comment: Probably, you may find your answer at the following link : 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229473/hashmap-one-key-multiple-values

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MultivalueMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) from Oracle or [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Google Guava.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Map<MyRange, List<String>>`. BTW you use [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) rather than `add` to set the associated key with its corresponding value

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Object,ArrayList<Object>> multiMap = new HashMap<Object,ArrayList<Object>>();
```