# I need to find a data structure

Tags: java

I need a data structure in java that can store 1 key and 2 pair values. 1 value needs to be a string and the other an int. 
I will also need to be able to put in and take out values and sort the pairs according to the int value.
Please help!

Comment: If you encapsulate that (String, int) pair into a meaningful class you can use a Map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashMap: One Key, multiple Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229473/hashmap-one-key-multiple-values)

Comment: Probably you may want to have a look over MultiMap(Google Guava library).Java standard development kit hasn't got MultiMap kind of data structure

Comment: No, this isn't a MultiMap.  That means multiple values of the same type; these are different types.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down to what you need:
1. you need something that store key->value, hence use `Map`
2. The key is String, no problem here.
3. the value is string/int pair, you can create such class:

```
public class MyPair {
 private String s;
 private int i;

 public MyPair(String s, int i) {
   this.s = s;
   this.i = i;
 } 
 // ommitting getters, hashcode and toString
}
```

4. You need it to be sorted by the int, so use `Comparable` interface:

```
public class MyPair implements Comparable<MyPair> {
 private String s;
 private int i;

 public MyPair(String s, int i) {
   this.s = s;
   this.i = i;
 } 

 public int compareTo(MyPair other) {
   return this.i - other.i;
 }
 // ommiting getters, hashcode and toString

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you use wrapper as mentioned in the other answers or you can use 2 maps one for the string and one for the Integer.

Comment: Surely the first one is preferred.  If the two items are related, it's better to encapsulate them together rather than maintaining two data structures.

Comment: I could not agree more, yet it is still an option depending on the case

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Option{

    private Integer id;
    private String value;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

make class and use