# return all value against one key in hashmap

Tags: java

I have one lookup file like this

```
REGEXP|Name
^.*?AAA.*?$|POP
^.*?AAA.*?$|SOP
^.*?BBB.*?$|ZOP
^.*?CCC.*?$|ROP
```

I have input string and matching my input string with this lookup file with REGEXP column. And where ever it matches, Its returning Name.

Step 1
I'm loading lookup file in my tool like this

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

Map<String, String> regexMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

globalMap.put("regexMap", regexMap);
```

Step 2

Loading lookup file in hashmap like this

```
Map<String, String> regexMap = (Map<String, String>)globalMap.get("regexMap");
 if( row1.REGEXP != null ) {
  regexMap.put( row1.REGEXP, row1.Name);
}
```

Step 3

Hitting input string with this hashmap like this

```
Map<String, String> regexMap = (Map<String, String>)globalMap.get("regexMap");
for( String key : regexMap.keySet() ) {
 if( input_row.data != null ) {
  if( input_row.data.matches(key) ) {
   output_row.Name = regexMap.get(key);
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

I'm getting one value only. I want all values with matches with single key.
Like in above mentioned lookup, If any string matches with first two REGEXP, output_row.Name should return POP and SOP both.
Right now its returning only SOP.

Is any thing am missing like using Array list or doing something wrong.

Suggestion please?

Comment: Java maps store exactly one value per key; if you want to store multiple "things" for a key, the value has to be some sort of collection.

Comment: MultiMap is what you need

Answer (score 0):

A map *can* store multiple values per key ... but you'll need to use a different container (e.g. a Map of List, or a MultiMap) instead of a HashMap:

[HashMap: One Key, multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229473/hashmap-one-key-multiple-values)

Comment: @paulsm4...Is anything I could change my in this existing code ? Do you think if I change my Map structure like this Map<String, List<String>> regexMap = (Map<String, List<String>>)globalMap.get("regexMap"); and change the type of Name from string to List...will work ?

Comment: I believe so.  The basic problem is that your unfortunate choice of "HashMap" will *NOT* work.  Please review the thread for details.