# HOW to change a string into character

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to change the string input to character  but when I run the code error occurs "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""  ".

```
    Map<Integer, Character> c = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
    Scanner sa = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i <3 ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter key");
       Integer a = sa.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value");
        char d = (char) Integer.parseInt(sa.nextLine());
        c.put(a,d);
    }
    System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Use `sa.nextLine()` before reading the value. See: [Issues with nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: You should be avoiding the use of the legacy `char` as it is limited to a subset of the Unicode characters (the “basic plane”).  Focus instead on using the code point numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, This will work for you please make sure that you should enter only one char while giving input, if you are giving string more than one chars then it will take first char only.

```
Map<Integer, Character> c = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
    Scanner sa = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i <1 ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter key");
       Integer a = sa.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value");
        //added new code 
        String str = sa.next();
        char d = str.charAt(0);
        c.put(a,d);
    }
    System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: it worked :).                                                                                                           But what will be the solution in more then one input.

Comment: @Einstein What do you mean by saying "more than one input"? Give an example.

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh like if I run the loop for 2 times it gives an error.

Comment: @Einstein Are you sure? I tested the above-mentioned code for various time, it works. What type of error do you get and what are your inputs?

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh if i input a same key for the two inputs. In output it gives only the last value and if i input different keys it output both values . can u tell why?.

Comment: @Einstein Well, honestly it is another question. Anyway, It is the nature of HashMap because it tends to have one key and one value. If you would like to have One-Key and Multiple-Value check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229518/3881354